# Compare dates in javascript which use 'D MMM YY - HH.MM.SS' formatting

Tags: javascript

I'm a little bit new to javascript (but not scripting in general).
Does anyone know a good way to compare dates which use this formatting? Need it for 'google script' if statements.

```
if ('14 Jul 16 - 16.34.06' > '5 May 17 - 08.24.27');
{
 ;do this
}

;another example
if ('7 Oct 16 - 09.19.55' < '28 Nov 16 - 02.06.12')
{
 ;do this
}
```

Should I use moment.js perhaps? Seems a bit big.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will have to parse the string to an date object, but since the string you provided is non-standart you have to do it manually with String.split/splice method. [MDN Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Then you can use ```>,<,===``` to compare both objects.

Comment: `const convert = dStr => { [ddmmmyy, hhmmss] = dStr.split(" - "); return new Date(\`${ddmmmyy} ${hhmmss.replace(/\./g,":")}\`);}`

Comment: i dont think const works for google script

Comment: neither does template literals

Comment: converted it to a working function like so:
```function convert(dStr)
{
    if (dStr == null)
      return;
    date = dStr.split(' - ');
    day = date[0].split(' ');
    date[1] = date[1].replace(/\./g,':')
    output = new Date(day[0] + ' ' + day[1] + ' 20' + day[2] + ' ' + date[1]); //had to add 20 in front of year here :(
    //Logger.log(output);
    return output;
}```

thanks again for the help!